# Using models in magnolia

Tags: java, spring-mvc, magnolia

Assuming that I have a controller such as the following:

```
@Controller
@Template(id= HomePageTemplate.ID, title = "Home Page")
public class HomePageTemplate {

    public static final String ID = "project:pages/home-page";

    @RequestMapping("/home-page")
    public String render(Model model, Node node) {

        model.addAttribute("meta", new MetaModel(node));
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to use the MetaModel in conjunction with `TemplatingFunctions` and other Magnolia items - but I am unsure how to access the content map from inside this model:

```
public class AbstractModel {

    protected Node node;

    protected TemplatingFunctions tf;

    public AbstractModel(Node node, @Inject TemplatingFunctions tf) {
        this.node = node;
        this.tf = tf;
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return tf.get("metaTitle");
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how I would get templating functions to inject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `new MetaModel(node)`, use

```
info.magnolia.objectfactory.Components.newInstance(MetaModel.class, node)
```

in order to create a new instance of your model. `TemplatingFunctions` will be automatically injected.

Another option would be to expose `TemplatingFunctions` as a Spring bean, somewhere in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public TemplatingFunctions templatingFunctions() {
    return Components.getComponent(TemplatingFunctions.class);
}
```

and just autowire the bean in your Spring controllers and add a new constructor to `MetaModel` class:

```
@Controller
@Template(id= HomePageTemplate.ID, title = "Home Page")
public class HomePageTemplate {

    @Autowired
    private TemplatingFunctions cmsfn;

    public String render(Model model, Node node) {
        model.addAttribute("meta", new MetaModel(node, cmsfn));
    }
}
```